# Can't start GUI programs via command line due to wrong DISPLAY variable

Tags: command-line, xorg, display-manager

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 and I cannot launch GUI programs via the command line. This applies to `subl` (for Sublime Text) and Firefox. When trying to start Firefox via CLI; it prints: `Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key`.

My environment shows:

```
➜ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

And I do have a file with that cookie:

```
➜ echo $XAUTHORITY 
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
➜ cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
voltaireMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1OZ��8�ص������v�voltaireMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1OZ��8�ص������v%
```

Also:

```
➜ xauth list
voltaire/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  4f5abfd438eb88d8b586f0fbad8aee76
#ffff#766f6c7461697265#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  4f5abfd438eb88d8b586f0fbad8aee76
```

It seems that two Xorg processes are running:

```
➜ ps aux | grep xorg
root      1400  0.0  0.1 213748 48068 tty1     Sl+  09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 7 -core
root      4701  1.9  0.5 658612 195732 tty2    Sl+  09:30   1:50 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 7 -core
```

I previously had lightdm installed to fix a login issue, and I have the current NVIDIA graphics drivers installed on my system. I guess this is very much related?

When I run:

```
DISPLAY=:1 subl
```

it works!

What could I do to fix this?

---

**Update**

I deleted `~/.Xauthority` and rebooted, but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that `DISPLAY` was incorrectly set to `:0.0` by a shell configuration file. Once I removed that, launching programs from the shell was possible again.

You can use this command to search through all the default shell configuration files:

```
grep "DISPLAY" ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login \
               ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile \
               /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
```

There are indeed two Xorg processes, which is [expected behavior](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041403/17529), so this should not be an issue in itself.

Also, the `.Xauthority` file does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: I am having same problem, can you specify which file you removed ? Searching display doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I did not remove an entire file. I just removed the `DISPLAY` line that was contained in one of the files.

Comment: One of files you listed above? My profile and bashrc doesn't contain any display line though.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam In my case it was the `.zshrc`.