# Gnome not recognizing secondary monitors, but xorg configuration works fine

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, gdm

I am having trouble getting GDM to make use of all of my screens. My hardware is connected like so:

Nvidia proprietary drivers 440.26

RTX 2070 super:

- DP: 1080p@144 monitor

GTX 670:

- DVI: 1080@60 monitor
- DVI: 1080@60 monitor
- HDMI: 4k@60 TV

It seems like xorg configuration is solid (see video), but gnome and xrandr are not taking the other displays into consideration.

Video: https://s1.webmshare.com/3jAB8.webm

Gnome desktop only shows on the primary monitor, but I can move the cursor correctly around all of the displays. When the cursor moves to a 'secondary' display the cursor changes to an X. It is not possible to drag windows over to the other displays, but it is possible to launch graphical applications using `DISPLAY=:0.1 xclock &`

Here is my xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.26

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1920 2160
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" Above "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ XL2420G"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     30.0 - 150.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VS247"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 135.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 670"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 670"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 670"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen          2
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_144 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 3840x2160 +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This seems like the same problem as this question: [Gnome ignoring second monitor Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194621/gnome-ignoring-second-monitor-ubuntu-19-10/1196291#1196291)

I have tried the suggested troubleshooting steps outline in the replies there, but no luck. When I enable Xinerama, I get a single '_' non blinking cursor in the top left of my primary monitor and nothing else when I reboot.

An important factor that separates my situation from referenced question is that I had no problems getting gnome to recognize all my display when using a similar setup using a 980 ti and my integrated graphics.

Here is the xorg.conf for that setup (intel/nvidia):

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 418.56

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ XL2420G"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 160.0
    VertRefresh     30.0 - 150.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "SamsungTV"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "intel0"
    Driver         "intel"
    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option         "TearFree" "true"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "true"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "nvidia0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +1920+2160 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "nvidia0"
    Monitor        "SamsungTV"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "metamodes" "3840x2160 +950+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "on"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "intel0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "intel0"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To verify that xrandr recognizes all monitors type `xrandr` at the command line and note which monitors are connected.

Comment: xrandr shows everything as 'disconnected' except for the primary display