# How to set up dual display with dual graphics card on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

I'm setting up PC with a pair of GeForce GTX 1070 (Both ASUS TURBO 1070) cards and a Philips 246E FHD monitors connected to each via DP(GPU-0) and HDMI(GPU-1).

PC config:

- DELL WorkStation Precision T7500 (2009 or 2010 made)
- CPU : X5690 * 2
- mem : 16GB * 12 (=192GB)
- GPU : ASUS TURBO GTX 1070 * 2 (not use SLI cable)
- Ubuntu display manager : gdm3

When I installed Ubuntu 20.04, I checked

- normal installation
- Download updates while installing Ubuntu
- installing third-party software for graphics and wifi hardware...

[image: Picture : install Ubuntu Checked settings]

I installed Ubuntu 20.04,then rebooted,second monitor (connected to GPU-1) doesn't work.

[image: Picture : second Philips monitor doesn't work]

So I set up "NVIDIA X SERVER SETTINGS" as follows.

[image: Picture : X SERVER SETTINGS for first monitor]

[image: Picture : X SERVER SETTINGS for second monitor]

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1920 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips PHL 246E7"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips PHL 246E7"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "GPU-bb9972e4-0457-d2b7-c62f-9aa988ef66e4.GPU-0.DP-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}, GPU-850dc788-8ca1-f53b-5edd-54c338e6fed5.GPU-1.HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
# Removed Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-6"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After rebooting, I still get GNOME on the one monitor. The other monitor, however, is a black screen with just the default X cursor (the glow on the right is just reflections on the monitor):

[image: Picture : X cursor on second monitor]

This is my nvidia-smi info.

```
Wed Aug 12 17:24:37 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 24%   56C    P0    39W / 151W |    462MiB /  8118MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:04:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 24%   37C    P8     7W / 151W |     54MiB /  8119MiB |     11%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1103      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            35MiB |
|    0      1707      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           206MiB |
|    0      1917      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         121MiB |
|    0      2830      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings                       3MiB |
|    0      3201      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      3278      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      3460      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      5499      G   ...094687058528,131072 --disable-features=    36MiB |
|    0      5731      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      5774      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      5830      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    0      7114      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
|    1      1103      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            14MiB |
|    1      1707      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            15MiB |
|    1      2830      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings                       0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I checked these pages for reference:

- [Gnome ignoring second monitor Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194621/gnome-ignoring-second-monitor-ubuntu-19-10)
- [4 monitors 2 nvidia video cards Ubuntu not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381961/4-monitors-2-nvidia-video-cards-ubuntu-not-working)
- [Arch Linux hydra build](https://collaboradev.com/2016/09/30/arch-linux-hydra-build/)

Comment: i have the same problem on debian 10 with GTX1060 and GT730, could you solve the problem?

Comment: I have similar issue (Dual GTX 1050 x 2, Benq Monitor x 4 ) , if running 20.04 in USB is ok, but not installed into HDD

Answer (score 0):

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/Xdmx.1.html describes the solution and the problem, I believe. There's a limit of 4 heads on x server without the mukti-head proxy set up (link is for this proxy's manual).