# nvidia-driver-450 Resolution & 2nd GPU Problem on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04, multiple-monitors

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer that has 2 monitors connected to the first GPU (Nvidia RX 2070 Super) and 2 monitors connected to the second GPU (Nvidia RX 2070 Super), there are 2 problems when using it with the GNOME desktop environment:

1. 2 of the monitors has no display signal when connected to the 2nd GPU, but has display signal when re-connected to the first GPU. `nvidia-driver-440` is used.
2. On updating to `nvida-driver-450`, the same problem persists. In addition, everything seems to be zoomed in, making application windows appear off screen when launched. Downgrading back to `nvidia-driver-440` solves this "zoomed in" issue.

NVIDIA X Server Settings show that 4 monitors are detected, but 2 of them (shared orange) are disabled and require a new X screen (X screen 1) to be created. Somehow, there is no option to set them to X screen 0.

[image]
*Screen cap showing the Display setings and NVIDIA X Server Settings after updating to `nvidia-driver-450`*

Any idea how we can fix this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Ubuntu 20.04(In my case, dual ASUS GTX 1070)

This is my question asked to DELL-community.
https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Fixed-Workstations/How-to-set-up-dual-monitor-with-dual-GTX-on-Ubuntu-20-04-or/m-p/7670304

Some people soleved issue like this.
[Gnome ignoring second monitor Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194621/gnome-ignoring-second-monitor-ubuntu-19-10)

I've tried everything I could bunt I couldn't solved my problem.
So, I re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 (Then NOT checked "install proprietary-driver")

I hope it helps you.